# Seam bijection and Weld

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam, cdi

I'm developing a JAVA EE 6 app. I'm using CDI extensively, My question is, are @Inject and @Produces the same as @In and @Out for Seam? Are @In and @Out annotations still used now that we have CDI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are @In and @Out annotations still
>   used now that we have CDI?

`@In` and `@Out` are Seam 2 annotations, so they are not used in Java EE 6.

> My question is, are @Inject and
>   @Produces the same as @In and @Out for
>   Seam?

`@Inject` and `@Produces` are *not* exactly the same but they are roughly equivalent. The main difference is that Java EE 6 dependencies are produced when *required* (controlled by the component which requires the dependency), while in Seam 2 outjection was performed as soon as something was *ready to be used* somewhere else (controlled by the component which provides the dependency)

Take a login as example:

- in Seam 2, the authenticated user was outjected into the desired scope (like session) immediately after having successfully logged in. The login component itself had a scope which usually fits the usecase (conversation), but *not* the scope of the provided dependency (session).
- in Java EE 6, a session-scoped login-component performs the authentication and stores the authenticated user in a private field. This field is then controlled by a producer method. So whenever another component requests the authenticated user, something like this is performed:

  ```
    @Produces @LoggedIn User getCurrentUser() {
        return user;
     }
  ```

Why is that? I hear you asking...

The reason is quite simple. Weld / Java EE 6 gains a huge performance boost from being able to proxy (most) dependencies. And it's simply not possible to proxy outjections :-)

Well, apart from that: the Java EE 6 demand-orientated approach (request it when you need it) feels superior to Seam 2 (produced it and store it away).

Comment: Jan, thanks for your very helpful answer. You mention @In and @Out are Seam 2 annotations, are they deprecated in seam 3?

Comment: More than that - they are not available. They are part of the Seam 2 jar, and this library is not deployed in JEE 6, so you cannot use them at all.

Comment: Seam2 != Seam3 Only the names are the same. Seam3 is a complete new implementation.